# Firebase anonymous authentication persistence on a device

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm using firebase for the backend of an IOS app written in **Swift3**.

I don't want my users to enter any kind of credentials so I'm using anonymous authentication.

In my `appDelegate` in the `application` func I'm calling :

```
 FIRAuth.auth()?.signInAnonymously() { (user, error) in
 ... }
```

That means that each time the user starts the app I'm calling this function. Until now, in my test phase, it works as I expected. Meaning that I get the same UID each time.

Is it safe to assume that I'll keep getting the same UID unless the user removes the app?

I saw that in `FIRUser` I can retrieve a Token using `getTokenWithCompletion`.
Shouldn't I use something to sign in using this Token instead of each time using `signInAnonymously`?

I tried with `func signIn(withCustomToken token: String, completion: FIRAuthResultCallback? = nil)` but saw afterward that this is used when using self-signed custom auth token. which is not the case here.

What I want to avoid is my user to start saving data and for whatever reason after X time losing all the data saved because they get signed in with a new UID.

Thanks and Regards

Comment: I have same doubt? Please let me know if you found good answer. Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: From a previous experience, when haven regular login with email and password, it will still have the same UID even when deleting the app, because actually the firebase session lives in the keychain of the phone. My guess is the same thing happens on anonymous logins